Python version in my VSCode notebook differs from the version of the virtual environment
Python environments confuse me very much. I had just formatted my PC and now I'm installing Anaconda+Python+VScode. First thing I did was to simply install Anaconda, with it Python version 3.11.7 was preinstalled. Then I created a virtual env conda create --name fbprophet. After which I installed VSCode and the Jupyter notebook extension, then created a .ipynb file. I'm then asked to select the kernel for the environment and at the moment I only have the (base) and the (fbprophet), both running on 3.11.7.
However, when doing a print(sys.version), it says I'm using Python 3.12.3!
I want to be able to work in the same venv, regardless of whether I'm writing a .py file or a .ipynb file. Can any one shed some light on how to get my way around this?


Please run %condal list in the running notebook and see if what the magic version says is running where the kernel runs is matching the sys.version. Have you restarted things? See here. Did you include installing the version of Python you want in the fbprophet env?

You have to select the python interpreter then choose your jupyter kernel in the upper right corner.

Read document for more details.
